# jQuery contentcarousel cloning failed to bind events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery carousel to scroll some items in a loop.

I have the following conditions to meet:

- When at the first item and the 'back' button is clicked, the last item has to shown.
- When at the last item and the 'next' button is clicked, the first item has to shown.

The elements in the carousel are `a` tags with click events bound to them. The items are shown in circular way but when I click items after case1 and case2 events are not fired.

After clone of items, the anchor is not bound to events and are not firing. My anchor onclick function is using a namespaced function.

Note: my code uses `clone(true)`

Code:

```
<a title="click me" href="" id="elementid"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="behavior.ID">GoClick</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="behavior.autobind.GoClick">onclick</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="behavior.GoClick.streamname">
        <xsl:value-of select="streamname" />
    </xsl:attribute> 
    click me 
</a> 

public void GoClickEventHandler(sender,args) { //do something here }
```

Comment: Could you please post the code you have.

Comment: looks my issue is related to bellow link.http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4537
Please any one can suggest the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I'm guessing here, but because you are creating elements dynamically after the page has loaded you will need to use `live()` or `delegate()` to bind the event handlers to them, instead of `click()`.

`Live()` is used like this:

```
$("#myAnchor").live("click", function() {
    // stuff to do on click
});
```

And `delegate()` (which has better performance) is used like this:

```
$("#anchorParent").delegate("#myAnchor", "click", function() {
    // stuff to do on click
});
```

Comment: I am using script#.With help of this my code will be in c# this will be converted te js. and my code looks like this

Comment: <a title="click me"  href="" id="elementid">   
                    <xsl:attribute name="behavior.ID">GoClick</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="behavior.autobind.GoClick">onclick</xsl:attribute>                    <xsl:attribute name="behavior.GoClick.streamname"><xsl:value-of select="streamname" /></xsl:attribute>                
                    click me
</a>


public void GoClickEventHandler(sender,args)
{
//do something here
}

Answer (score 0):

For the jQuery carousel to be circular you have to do this:

```
// Looping carousel
$("div").carousel( { loop: true } );
```

The `loop: true` option will make it circular.

Comment: I am not facing looping issue .Items are looped well  when i click next and prev.But the issue is onclick event associated with the items are not firing when i click on looped item.